# Last element of a struct disappearing on write/read

Tags: c++, struct

I'm building a weather station with two UNOs, using NRF24l01+ radios. Communications are fine. I'm sending a struct from one to the other. The struct has three elements:

```
    struct weather {
      float tempData;
      float humData;
      float pressData;
    };
    weather wData = {0, 0, 0};
```

I then populate the struct with values from my DHT22 Temperature Sensor and my BMP085 pressure sensor.

```
    float c = dht.readTemperature();
    wData.tempData = (c * 9/5) + 32;
    wData.humData = dht.readHumidity();

    sensors_event_t event;
    bmp.getEvent(&event);
    wData.pressData = (0.0295 * event.pressure);
```

Now I send it via the NRF24L01+.

```
    radio.write(&wData, sizeof(wData);
```

On the receiving Uno I have this.

```
    struct weather {
      float tempData;
      float humData;
      float pressData;
    };

    weather wData = {0, 0, 0};

    radio.read( &wData, sizeof(wData) );
    Serial.println(wData.tempData);
    Serial.println(wData.humData);
    Serial.println(wData.pressData);
```

I get results similar to this:

```
    Temp = 75.43
    Hum = 35.76
    Press = 0.00
```

The first two are correct. The final one is not. I can change the order and the first two will always be correct, but the last element is always 0.00. For example:

```
   Hum = 35.76
   Press = 30.14
   Temp = 0.00
```

I know I'm missing something here with my code but I can't find it. Anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: `read()` and `write()` return a `bool`, did you try to get it and print it to `Serial`, just to check both functions consider everything's OK? That might help.

Comment: Also, did you check that the `weather` on the emiiter contained a non-0 pressure before `write()`?

Comment: The line with `radio.write(...` is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: `read()` and `write()` return 1. Missed the closing parenthesis while moving code here but it's there in my code.

Comment: After taking a look at the RF24 library source code, I wonder if you have changed the payload size before read or write. To know about it, you should `Serial.println()` of `radio.getPayloadSize()` in both sketches; normally that should be `32` by default, but I wonder about it...

Comment: With the `struct' populated the size is `12`.

Comment: The documentation mentions ["Be sure to call openWritingPipe() first"](http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#a4cd4c198a47704db20b6b5cf0731cd58) before calling write().

Comment: @brorobw, @jfpoilpret was asking about the payload size set on your `radio` variable, because the behavior you're seeing is consistent with writes being truncated at 8 bytes. The `RD24` class truncates/pads all writes to a fixed size, so you should check what that fixed size is set to.

Answer (score 2):

Modified my `struct` by changing the first two elements from `float` to `int`.

```
struct weather {
  int tempData;
  int humData;
  float pressData;
}
weather wData;
```

**Everything transmits fine now.** I don't really need the precision of a `float` for temperature and humidity. However, I would still like to find the problem. Could there be some problem with the size of three `floats` versus two `ints` and a `float`? `Serial.print(sizeof(wData))` is `12` when all elements are `floats` and `8` when using two `int` and a `float`. My understanding is the NRF24L01+ has a transmit and receive buffer of 32 bytes.

Comment: Have you tried the opposite, ie putting 4 floats instead of just 2? Maybe transmission is done by pack of 8 bytes?

Comment: Have not tried that. Will try soon and report back.

Comment: Did you try testing with a known strings of different lengths instead of your struct.

Comment: Have note tried anything else as of yet. Work and life getting in the way!